How to install up-to-date SSL certificates on iphone 4/ iOS 7?
My iphone 4 running iOS 7.1.2 and Safari cannot access certain SSL website, e.g. https://letsencrypt.org, presumably because of expired certificates. Installing the profile provided at https://blog.jjhayes.net/wp/2021/11/13/fix-old-iphone-4-4s-ios-7-ssl-certificate-errors/ did not help. (I am using a passcode on the device.) Is there some other method to update the trust store?
